# get the list of authors in a git repository efficiently with libgit2

Tags: git, rust, libgit2

I need to get the list of authors for a git repository, like `git shortlog -s` does in the command line.

What I'm doing currently, and works, is to do a revwalk (going over all the revisions) and collecting the list of authors for all the commits one at a time, but this is quite slow, especially compared to the command-line git command.

I am using rust but I expect the solution is similar in C or another language binding to libgit2.

This is my current, working, but slow, code:

```rust
        let repo = Repository::open(&git_path)?;
        let mut revwalk = repo.revwalk()?;
        revwalk.push_head()?;
        let mut authors: Vec<String> = revwalk
            .map(|r| {
                let oid = r?;
                repo.find_commit(oid)
            })
            .filter_map(|c| match c {
                Ok(commit) => Some(commit),
                Err(e) => {
                    println!("Error walking the revisions {}, skipping", e);
                    None
                }
            })
            .fold(HashSet::new(), |mut sofar, cur| {
                if let Some(name) = cur.author().name() {
                    sofar.insert(name.to_string());
                }
                sofar
            })
            .into_iter()
            .collect();
        authors.sort();
```

**EDIT** Ok when building with rust in release mode it is noticeably faster. I still wonder whether there's not a more efficient way still.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a more efficient way, unfortunately, unless you know something about the repository structure (e.g., that all commits before a certain point are made by a certain user).  If you want to know something about every commit, you have to necessarily traverse every commit.  Git doesn't provide a cache for this information, so walking the history is required.

libgit2, being a bit more generic, may not be able to take advantage of the same optimizations as Git itself, but overall the algorithm is the same.

Answer (score 3):

The general algorithm is as good as it gets: you must walk each commit in order to gather all author names, there's no way around it.

Nitpick: You are allocating a `String` for the author's name for each commit. It might be faster to check if the name is already in the set first, which works with just a `&str` (`!sofar.contains(name)`).

On nightly, you could change `sofar.insert(name.to_string());` to `sofar.get_or_insert_with(name, str::to_string);`. [`get_or_insert_with`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/struct.HashSet.html#method.get_or_insert_with) will only perform one lookup, instead of two with the `contains`/`insert` pair.

Comment: Thank you for the insightful comment! I was more looking for another way entirely to collect this data from the git format, but this is very helpful too!